# Do Ryzen 3 2200u laptops with Vega 3 work out of the box with major Linux distros?

Tags: linux, laptop, intel, amd, hardware-compatibility

Does a laptop with Ryzen 3 2200u and Vega 3 work without issues with stock install of Debian 9 or Ubuntu 18.04?

I dont want to install drivers! Not to mention compile a patched kernel.

I have to choose between Core i3 6006u and Ryzen 3 2200u.

I know that Intel SoCs work out of the box on Linux. So they seem like a safe choice.

Any experiences? Does anyone of you own such a laptop?